# Redirecting output of terminal to file

Tags: linux, bash, io-redirection

I'm trying to redirect the output of a command from a terminal to a text file.
My command is:

```
rails_best_practices . > rbp.txt
```

It works fine but the contents of the file is a bit different.

`[1;31m/Users/carlwilliamtablante/www/serviceseeking/db/schema.rb:16 - always add db index (abns => [provider_account_id])[0m`

[image]

As you can see in the screenshot, it outputs an `ESC` character, but when trying to view it on the reminal using `cat`, it should display the line number. So how do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://github.com/railsbp/rails_best_practices: you can use `--without-color` to omit the colour codes.